# How can I get the id the dynamic ID of input type?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to build like unlike system on PHP AJAX. I'm almost done but the way I am doing it is not correct I think.

Here is the code:

```
<?php $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM posts");
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

 ?>         
 <table border="1" width="50%" align="center" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <!-- Name -->
            <strong><?php echo $data["author"] ?></strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- post content -->
            <?php echo $data["content"]; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> 
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>" id="like<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>">
        <button type="submit" id="likebtn<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>">Like</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //displaydata();
        // body...

        $("#likebtn"+<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>).click(function(){
            var like= $("#like"+<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>).val();


            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type:"POST",
                async:false,
                data:{
                    "done":1,
                    "id" : like,
                },
                success:function(data){
                    //displaydata();
                    //$("#like").val('');
                }
            });


        }); 

    });
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

The problem is AJAX code is in the loop so if there is multiple posts the code repeats multiple times which I don't want, and if I put the AJAX code out of the loop then only the first button data is executed because the ID is same of all posts. I can create a dynamic ID for each post but how can I use dynamic ID in AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use class for each Dynamic buttons

So your this code

```
<button type="submit" id="likebtn<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>">Like</button></td>
```

should be

```
<button type="submit" class="btnSubmit" id="likebtn<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>">Like</button></td>
```

And you can use it in ajax like this

```
$(".btnSubmit").click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        async:false,
        data:{
            "done":1,
            "id" : id,
        },
        success:function(data){
            //displaydata();
            //$("#like").val('');
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: How about a `data-` attribute instead of an `id`, since you are suggesting a class-based selector?  Then the value can be a raw / unprefixed number/id ...this avoids having to chop up the data on the other end to isolate the id number.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not submitting via a form, you don't need to declare a `name` attribute, nor `type="submit"`.  You don't even need to declare an `id` or a `class`.  You can write an `onclick` event to all `<button>` tags and access the dynamic data which is best/logically stored in a `data-id` attribute using `this`.

First build your buttons in your php loop like this:

```
echo "<button data-id=\"{$data['id']}\">Like</button>";
```

This should output html similar to this:

```
<button data-id="1">Like</button>
<button data-id="2">Like</button>
<button data-id="3">Like</button>
<button data-id="4">Like</button>
```

In your javascript, (after the page is loaded) you can write your event function like so:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        async:false,
        data:{
            "done" : 1,
            "id" : $(this).data("id")
        },
        ...
    });
});
```

Here is a little jsfiddle demonstration:  https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/20542/

Comment: Hi Thanks! i try this code and its work fine if its under loop but as expect the code execute multiple times because there are multiple no. of `<button>` but when i put this code out of the loop its did'nt work for me

Comment: Please show me your entire script (send me a https://3v4l.org hyperlink or similar) so that I can review your work.

Comment: @Yash let's progress the status of this page toward a system-recognized resolution.   Please show me your implementation of my solution so that I can offer my support.